# Pandas switching Timestamp when using .unique()

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm wondering what's going on in pandas with the below sequence, and how I can work around it?:

```
In [88]: d = {1:{'idx':pd.Timestamp('2014-06-16 03:49:23.088652')}}

In [89]: x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')

In [90]: x
Out[90]:
                         idx
1 2014-06-16 03:49:23.088652

[1 rows x 1 columns]

In [91]: x.idx.unique()
Out[91]: array([1970-01-17 59:49:23.088652], dtype=datetime64[ns])

In [92]: pd.__version__
Out[92]: '0.13.1'
```

The problem I'm having comes from trying something like this:

```
In [93]: idxs = x.idx.unique()

In [94]: idxs[0]-pd.tseries.offsets.Milli(40)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/cschwalbach/as_research_repo/logs/<ipython-input-94-914fa6d4ff6a> in <module>()
----> 1 idxs[0]-pd.tseries.offsets.Milli(40)

TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'
```

Comment: This is a display issue with numpy < 1.7. Doesn't actually matter as it won't affect anything (as pandas does all datetime math internally).

Comment: You can use this as a great chance to upgrade both `numpy` and `pandas`! :^)

Comment: See here for an explanation (scroll down a bit): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#numpy-datetime64-dtype-and-1-6-dependency (this is 2+ years old)

Comment: I added the issue I'm having. I have upgraded pandas recently but I rely on outside scripts that I can't update numpy with. I could likely go to .14(Haven't tried it in my venv), but it sounds like that would not matter

Comment: For my issues with upgrading, would there be a good workaround? I prefer it to be in a column without a tz, as I'm comparing it to another value that is tz=None.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append nanos (since numpy datetime arrays* don't understand pandas offsets):

```
In [11]: idxs[0] - pd.tseries.offsets.Milli(40).nanos
Out[11]: numpy.datetime64('2014-06-15T20:49:23.048652000-0700')
```

**The `unique` method returns a numpy array rather than a pandas object...*

Note this should "just work" with (recent) pandas objects (Series):

```
In [12]: x['idx'] - pd.tseries.offsets.Milli(40)
Out[12]:
1   2014-06-16 03:49:23.048652
Name: idx, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Using nanos is still giving me 1970-01-17 59:49:23.088652. Also what I'm doing is actually a subset of the main dataframe using the idx. Looks like this currently: master[idx-pd.tseries.offsets.Milli(40).nanos:idx+pd.tseries.offsets.Milli(100).nanos]

Comment: @user1610719 I'm not sure how you want that slicing to work, usually you'd slice be a single date (rather than an array)...

Comment: If I wanted everything between 2014-06-24 and the hours of 9am to 10am, I would slice in this way. I'm dealing with millions of rows and in this example need to check for something within ~150 milliseconds of a time I'm using